# Get middle name from Facebook API by the .NET Middleware

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I try to get some basic data from Facebook API, by using the .NET Middleware (I'm using ASP.NET 5, but I think it's similar in older versions) for authentication by facebook.

I have no problems with first name, last name and so on, but I'm stuck to get the middle name, here is my code snippet:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.AuthenticationType = "Facebook";
            options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType;
            options.AppId = facebookAppId;
            options.AppSecret = facebookAppSecret;
            options.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Notifications = new Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async (ctx) =>
                {
                    var token = ctx.AccessToken;

                    var firstName = ctx.User["first_name"];
                    var middleName = ctx.User["middle_name"];
                    var lastName = ctx.User["last_name"];
                }
            }
       }
```

I tried to add "middle_name" to the scope, but it throw a error from FB:

> Invalid Scope: middle_name

Comment: well, what error would that be?

Comment: I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

You should add `middle name` in scope. Like this.

`options.Scope.Add("middle_name");`

First name and last name might be the implicit values you are getting,  for middle name you have to add it to scope to get the value.

And you should add this to scope to corresponding facebook App, that you have created ( I mean you are using corresponding app key/secret, that facebook App).

Comment: But where can I add this scope in the corresponding facebook app? I use the app key/secret, but I don't see there any settings for ask for additional scopes?

Comment: First, you can try adding this code to your existing code, else you might have got app key/secret in `developer.facebook.com`, where you have created App, there i was telling to put this scope.